# Any tool can help refactor field into get/set pairs of method

Tags: java, refactoring, automated-refactoring

Wondering if there is tool to assist this kind of refactoring.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Eclipse is an awesome IDE!
[image: right click, go to Source, "Generate Getters and Setters..."]

... or...

[image]

---

In Netbeans...
[image: right click, go to Refactor, "Encapsulate Fields"]

Comment: +1, but - Eclipse also has Encapsulate Field under the Refactor menu, and that is more powerful than Generate Getters and Setters, in that it applies the new methods to existing field references.  So don't forget about that command!

Comment: ahh... Thanks! I haven't noticed that before... I don't usually use these shortcuts to create my getters and setters.

Answer (score 2):

It's a standard feature of the eclipse IDE (and of other IDEs too, I suppose).

Shortcut: <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> -> <kbd>r</kbd> shows the getter/setter dialog (if a class with class members was selected)

BTW - autogenerating getter/setter stubs for class members is not a *refactoring*.

---

> **Code refactoring** is "a disciplined way to restructure code", undertaken in order to improve some of the nonfunctional attributes of the software. ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refactoring))

Autogenerating those stubs does not restructure the (existing) code. It automatically adds method implementations. And, if we look at eclipse, we don't find the according action in the list of refactorings (additional hint).

Further Reading: [Self Encapsulate Field](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/selfEncapsulateField.html)

Comment: What do you mean by your "BTW" comment? Encapsulating fields is most certainly a kind of [code refactoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refactoring). Or perhaps you mean something else by "autogenerating getter/setter stubs" than encapsulating fields.

Comment: @Ted - have a look at my additions to the answer.

Comment: @Andreas_D - Look at the "List of refactoring techniques" in that Wikipedia article we both referenced; you'll find "Encapsulate Field – force code to access the field with getter and setter methods". More generally, [dictionary.reference.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/refactoring) defines refactoring to be "Improving a computer program by reorganising its internal structure without altering its external behaviour." Don't treat the Eclipse menu structure as authoritative computer terminology.

Comment: @Ted - there we have the difference. Implementing setters/getters **is not a** refactoring, but forcing existing code to use them **is a** refactoring. It changes direct access to class members to calls to getter/setter method. A pure refactoring.

Comment: @Andreas_D - It's kind of a silly argument, here, isn't it? But I'll continue it a bit anyway. :) Changing the external behavior of a single class, even if it forces corresponding changes to other parts of the program, is not the same as changing the behavior of a program. So I don't understand your argument. And since you propose using IDE menu structures as authoritative, I'll point out that NetBeans, unlike Eclipse, does put "Encapsulate Fields" under Refactor.

Comment: @Ted - it becomes silly because you start speaking of something different. Check out Martin Fowler. [Self Encapsulate Field](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/selfEncapsulateField.html). **Only** adding getter/setter is **not** a refactoring. Doing this **and** changing existing code to use the new getters/setters is a refactoring. You **have** to change something that already exists.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse has the functionality of generate getters and setters.

```
Source > Generate setters and getters
```

Source: [Generate Getters and Setters](http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2005/09/04/eclipse-tool-tip-1-getters-and-setters/)

Comment: Once he's done that, he needs to change the attributes to `private` and then find / fix the compilation errors by using the getter / setter methods.

Answer (score 2):

eclipse provides this. You can use my plugin as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733311/copy-field-and-methods/2734647#2734647.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what IDE you use, this is a standard feature provided. For instance, in [Netbeans](http://blogs.oracle.com/charliebrown/entry/encapsulating_fields_aka_generating_getters) - right click on your java class and choose Refactor -> Encapsulate Fields. You can additionally select the accessors visibility, order of appearance and insert point.